# Sequences of Complex numbers (proofs )

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

How can one prove using ($\epsilon$ and $N$) that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \left\{\frac{1 + i}{2}\right\}^n = 0. $$

I have tried the usual tricks one does with sequences, but nothing seems to work... Please help

Comment: Is that the limit over $n$ or $\lim n\left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^n$?

Comment: Hi your second statement is what I mean.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider (1+i)/2 in polar coordinates.

(1 + i)/2 = sqrt(1/2)* e^(iPi/4)

The modulus (magnitude) of this is sqrt(1/2).

So the nth term in your sequence has magnitude n * (sqrt(1/2))^n

= n/2^n which obviously approaches zero has n -> infinity.

The only complex number with modulus 0 is 0.

Comment: Thanks Peter for answering this question but I think that my book wanted an epsilon argument like the one provided by copper hat......

Comment: I guess the $\epsilon$ proof deteriorated with age?

Answer (score 2):

Since $|1+i| = \sqrt{2}$, we have $|n ( {1+i \over 2})^n| = {n \over (\sqrt{2})^n}$.

Since $\sqrt{2}>1$, and $(\sqrt{2})^n=(1+(\sqrt{2}-1))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (\sqrt{2}-1)^k \ge \binom{n}{2} (\sqrt{2}-1)^2$, we have
${n \over (\sqrt{2})^n} \le {n \over {{1 \over 2} n (n-1)}(\sqrt{2}-1)^2  } = {2 \over (\sqrt{2}-1)^2} {1 \over n-1}$.

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and let $N = 1+ {2 \over (\sqrt{2}-1)^2} {1 \over \epsilon}$.
Then if $n \ge N$ we have  $|n ( {1+i \over 2})^n| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is an amazing proof...